# How can I loop this PHP code for six times exactly?

Tags: php, html, arrays, loops

OK, this is my code:

```
    <?php if (!empty($projectSectorItem1Title)): ?>
    <div class="project" style="overflow:hidden;">
        <?php if (!empty($projectSectorItem1Image)) { ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $projectSectorItem1Image; ?>" width="100%"/>
        <div class="project_box_info">
            <h3><a><?php echo $projectSectorItem1Title; ?></a></h3>
            <p><?php echo $projectSectorItem1Description; ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <div class="project_box_info" style="opacity:1;">
            <h3><a><?php echo $projectSectorItem1Title; ?></a></h3>
            <p><?php echo $projectSectorItem1Description; ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

This code is repeated currently in my .php file six times, as I have up to six items. If the first if statement returns false, naturally nothing appears. This is good. It works. However, I've noticed my page is loading slower now with six of these stacked up on each other.

Is there a way to systematically loop this exact code for each of the numbers? The only thing that would need to change is the numbers.. i.e. above #1, second #2, third #2 etc. Lines containing numbers that need to increase are: 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 11, 12. So there are 7 places. I have no idea how to do this!

I have a similar issue in the same .php file, but if I know how to do this one, I should be able to "kill two birds with one stone" as they say. Many thanks for any help.

To clarify what I'm trying to do for one of the commenters: I have six boxes which are associated with meta data for each item inside each box. If the title variable is filled in, we go ahead with the rest of the code. However, if there is no image, there is no "hover" feature; instead, the opacity of the hover box is already filled (hence that opacity:1; in the second bit).

So... check for title > if title exists, go ahead > if image, proceed as normal but if not > proceed as normal without the image and set opacity to 1 for project_box_info

Really I'm just reiterating the code here in English, but that's all I can do really!

Comment: Consider having an array of indexed values instead of manually naming the variables. That way, you can use a loop more effectively.

Comment: I really think you need to re-think your question. Rather than asking us how to implement your (quite frankly, pretty bad) solution the best way, give us your end goal and someone will probably come up with a better general way of doing it.

Comment: It should be noted that even if you output this in a loop, it will not have an effect on your page load time.  You would still have the same amount of HTML source output.

Comment: I think this is where you have to use `double dollar sign operator`

Comment: please try the code below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a forloop like below

```
<?php for($i=1;$i<=6;$i++): ?>
<?php if (!empty(${"projectSectorItem{$i}Title"})): ?>
<div class="project" style="overflow:hidden;">
    <?php if (!empty(${"projectSectorItem{$i}Image"})) { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo ${"projectSectorItem{$i}Image"}; ?>" width="100%"/>
    <div class="project_box_info">
        <h3><a><?php echo ${"projectSectorItem{$i}Title"}; ?></a></h3>
        <p><?php echo ${"projectSectorItem{$i}Description"}; ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <div class="project_box_info" style="opacity:1;">
        <h3><a><?php echo ${"projectSectorItem{$i}Title"}; ?></a></h3>
        <p><?php echo ${"projectSectorItem{$i}Description"}; ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

That is your loop.. Feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry the delay. Yes this is perfect! It already works. I'm now going to look at this other guy's array also. Really appreciate it though. I'm going to see what happens with the other code though (different approach). Otherwise I'll stick with this.

Answer (score 1):

You would use a for loop;

```
<?
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    // your code here
}
```

This would loop through the above statement 6 times. If you want to change a number, you could substitute in for i - (or i+1);

```
<?
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    echo("this is cycle number $i");
}
```

Would return with;
this is cycle 0
this is cycle 1
this is cycle 2

Comment: Thanks for this, same as Haroon except he went ahead and did the entire thing. This was nice and basic though, good for getting familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for something along these lines.

Having an array of items with set titles, descriptions and image urls should greatly increase the execution speed. Then, as others have suggested, loop over the array with a `for` or `foreach`.

Using this method better separates the data from the presentation, which makes the whole thing easier to read and modify.

```
$items = array(
    array(
        'title' => 'Item 1',
        'description' => 'This is the description for item1',
        'image' => 'http://fake.com/images/item1.png'
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Item 2',
        'description' => 'This is the description for item2',
        'image' => 'http://fake.com/images/item2.png'
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Item 3',
        'description' => 'This is the description for item3'
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Item 4',
        'description' => 'This is the description for item4',
        'image' => 'http://fake.com/images/item4.png'
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Item 5',
        'description' => 'This is the description for item5',
        'image' => 'http://fake.com/images/item5.png'
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Item 6',
        'description' => 'This is the description for item6'
    )
)

foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo '
    <div class="project">
        ', (isset($item['image']) ? '<img src=' . $item['image'] . '" alt="" />' : ''), '
        <div class="project_box_info">
            <h3><a>', $item['title'], '"</a></h3>
            <p>', $item['description'], '"</p>
        </div>
    </div>';
}
```

I did omit your inline styles here for the sake of readability. Really they should be in an external stylesheet anyway.

Comment: Here's a [quick explanation](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) of shorthand conditions in PHP (ternary operators), just in case you haven't used them before. Use with caution, as they can get out of hand very quickly.